# Android Studio: Reading From Internal Storage Decoding Issues

Tags: android, fileinputstream, internal-storage, android-internal-storage

I have a problem with reading from an internal storage file in Android Studio for an Android application I am making. I have an application that has an edittext which users can enter text. Then, on a button click, I save this text in INTERNAL STORAGE for future use.

However, when I load the file from internal storage back onto the edittext, the process I am using changes certain characters (***Especially for languages other than english) to odd symbols. For example, if I enter using Russian text, save the file, and try to load it, it will be a bunch of jumbled symbols and letters.

Here is the code for SAVING TO INTERNAL STORAGE:

```
            String codeData = htmlCode.getText().toString();

            try {
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = getActivity().openFileOutput("MyFile.html", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
                //byte[] bytes = htmlCode.getText().toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                fileOutputStream.write(codeData.getBytes("UTF-32"));
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

Here is the code for LOADING FROM INTERNAL STORAGE:

```
        String putThisStringinEditText = "";

        try {

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = getActivity().openFileInput("MyFile.html");

            int c;
            String temp = "";
            while ((c = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);

            }

            putThisStringinEditText = temp;

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Also, note*** I know that the problem is not with saving the file, because I have other ways of testing that and I have identified the problem as originating from loading the file.

Comment: No the problem is that you save the file utf-32 but at loading you are not using utf-32.

Comment: Why would you save a file utf-32?

Comment: You better use .writeLine() and .readLine().